# Django - How to add a file during model save?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to create and save a csv file as part of a save and then associate the file to the record.

This is my model

```
class ReOrder (models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product,
    )
    order_quantity = models.IntegerField(
        default = 0
    )
    order_date = models.DateField(
        default = datetime.datetime.now()
    )
    received = models.BooleanField(
        default = False
    )
    order_file = models.FileField(
        upload_to = 'reorder_documents/',
        null = True,
        blank = True
    )
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.product)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # create the text file 
        filename =  str(self.product)+'_'+str(self.order_date)+".csv"
        path = os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, 'reorder_documents', filename)
        print path
        f = open(path, 'wrb')
        f.truncate()
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow((self.product, self.order_quantity))
        f.close()
        self.order_file = ContentFile(f)

        #save everything
        super(ReOrder, self).save(*args, **kwargs)  # Call the "real" save() method.
```

This creates and saves the file exactly where I want it but doesn't save it to the model.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django's FileField stores only string in DB so you can save only filepath:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # create the text file 
    filename =  str(self.product)+'_'+str(self.order_date)+".csv"
    path = os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, 'reorder_documents', filename)
    print path
    f = open(path, 'wrb')
    f.truncate()
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow((self.product, self.order_quantity))
    f.close()
    self.order_file = os.path.join('reorder_documents', filename)
    super(ReOrder, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```